# shiny: Is it possible to apply two different text size within the same title in a tabPanel()?

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, shinyapps

I have the following `tabPanel()`

[image]

Written with

```
tabsetPanel(id = "something", 
              tabPanel(title = HTML(paste("Gross Total Resection", 
                                          "Simpson Grade I-III", sep = "<br/>")), br(),
                       plotOutput("surv_nom",width = "90%", height="650px")))
```

**Question:** is it possible to apply two different text sizes within the same `tabPanel()-title`?

The expected output looks something like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with HTML functions, see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson2/) for more info.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(title = HTML(paste(h4("Gross Total Resection"),
                                p("Simpson Grade I-III", align = "center")
                                )
                          )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```